# using lan and wifi at same time for different apps in windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, download-manager

i have 2 internet in my house one is ADSL and the other is LTE. as you may know LTE provide higher speed but it's a little bit expensive for high data usage and ADSL provide lower speed than LTE but it's usually have unlimited data usage. so everytime i want to download big data files i have to connect to ADSL but downloading with ADSL will consume whole bandwidth speed and it's impossible to use internet for other purposes until download is finished.

i wanted to know is it possible to connect to ADSL with lan and connect to LTE with wifi and use them at the same time but over different apps? for example my download manager use ADSL to download and my browser use LTE for surfing internet, streaming and so on.

Comment: It's entirely possible to have two such networks alive at the same time. The trick will be to make the download manager use a non-default network. Which download manager are you using?

Comment: i mainly use IDM for downloading and firefox for browsing. but beside that i may sometime download with other software like steam for downloading games